# google chrome v113 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS - Sites are not displayed properly

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MsPD.png)a I am experiencing some problem with viewing the sites on google chrome latest stable, more or less - sites are not generating properly at all - screenshot attached.Any advice?

I tried purge, uninstalling, clearing, nothing worked. FF and Chromium OK

Comment: tell more about you system. Do you use x11 or Wayland, what about graphic drivers?

Answer (score 1):

remove cache from
`~/.config/google-chrome/Default$ rm -rf GPUCache/`

Answer (score 1):

to anyone experiencing the same problem after latest google chrome update - I have just solved the issue it works like a charm now.

Solution in my case:

I have **Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)** after using this laptop for over a year now it turns out I have to install graphic card drivers, otherwise it wouldn't display pages correctly as above - but it was OK, decided not to work after lates update btw

Solution in my case:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Thanks ubuntu community you're the best :*